# Can a complex Radon measure be approximated by compactly supported Radon measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups, borel-measures

Let $G$ be an (abelian) locally compact Hausdorff group. Consider the following fragment from Folland's text "A course in abstract harmonic analysis" (second edition, p102).

[image]

Why is the boxed line true? I guess formally, the statement we should prove is the following:

If $\mu \in M(G)$, there exists a sequence $\{\mu_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq M(G)$ such that $\|\mu_n -\mu\|\to 0$ and such that $\mu_n$ has support on a compact set (i.e. there exists a compact subset $K_n\subseteq G$ such that $\mu_n(A)=\mu_n(A\cap K_n)$ for all Borel subsets $A\subseteq G$.

Is this statement true? If so, how can we prove this? I have no idea how to construct such a sequence of measures (especially if $G$ is not assumed to be $\sigma$-compact, but even that simpler case remains elusive to me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mu $ be in $M(G)$, so that $\mu $ is a Radon measure with finite total variation.  This said we see that  $|\mu |$ is  a finite Radon
measure and hence regular, so there are compact sets $K_n$ such that $|\mu|(G\setminus K_n)\to 0$.  You may then define $\mu_n$ by
$$\mu_n(E):=\mu(E\cap K_n),$$
in which case $$
  \|\mu-\mu_n\|=
  |\mu-\mu_n|(G) = $$$$=
  |\mu-\mu_n|(K_n) +   |\mu-\mu_n|(G\setminus K_n) =$$$$=
 0+|\mu|(G\setminus K_n)\to 0.
$$

Comment: Some remarks: (1) This kind of regularity only makes sense for positive measures, so you should replace $\mu$ by $|\mu|$. (2) Your first claim is false. For instance, take $G= \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ Lebesgue measure. Then $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus K) = \infty$ for any compact set. In particular, a sequence $\mu(G\setminus K_n)$ can never converge to $0$.

Comment: I believe $M(G)$ means the set of measures of finite total variation.  Otherwise there is no hope of finding the $\mu_n$.

Comment: I acknowledge your remark about positive measures and I'll edit as soon as I can.

Comment: Of course! $M(G)$ consist of complex Radon measures, which are necessarily finite!